# Prevent UITableviewcell from becoming transparent during reordering

Tags: uitableview, transparent

I am trying to keep my uitableviewcells opaque during reorder animation - reason being that I am doing custom drawing of the cell in one view to enhance scroll performance, but doing this slows down the reorder animation significantly.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I feel dumb for asking this question XD

I just figured out that in my drawrect function, I can override alpha value.  so, in the beginning of the draw, I just set self.alpha = 1.0f, and voila my cells are opaque in all modes, including in middle of reordering.

Comment: hi, i have this situation, do you know how to preserve original layout when reordering cells? 

original solution video(not working): https://vid.me/j6wy
following your tips: https://vid.me/Df4p,

Answer (score 9):

For an excellent description of what is going on when the table is in dragging mode, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21041704/35690).

I had a UITableViewStyleGrouped on iOS 7. In order to get the desired effect (non-transparent, white background), I had to follow [Aaron's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21619610/35690) suggestion and [bmovement's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13158863/35690).

```
@interface ABCCell : UITableViewCell

@end

@implementation ABCCell

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundView = [UIView new];
        self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
    [super setAlpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

Not doing either causes the view to have a 100% transparent background.

Setting just the background view causes the cell to have a 80% transparent white background.

Setting just the alpha causes the cell to have a black background (0% transparent).

Implementing both, gives you a white background (0% transparent).

Comment: For a slightly more portable approach (assuming you are creating custom table cell views visually and are setting the background color of the content view), you could set your new background color like this:  `self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = self.contentView.backgroundColor;`

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me. It was important to set the background view in initWithCoder and not (just) initWithStyle.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, my `UITableViewCell` subclass's drawRect wasn't being called when the reorder animation began, but adding this to my subclass worked for me:

```
- (void)setAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
    [super setAlpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: This does not work when you user a png image with transparence as your cell's background image.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but this issue can come up again for cells in table views with style `UITableViewStyleGrouped` on iOS 7.  These cells should have a non-nil background view by default, but staring in iOS 7 the background view is either not set or is not given an opaque background.  To prevent the cells from becoming transparent during reorder, add code like this in the cell class's `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method (or somewhere else around the initialization of the cells).  Here `self` is the cell itself.

```
self.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // Or whatever color.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for Swift.

```
class StopMakingMeTransparentCell: UITableViewCell {
    override var alpha: CGFloat {
        didSet {
            super.alpha = 1
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.backgroundView = UIView()
        self.backgroundView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An most up to date answer for this problem, in Swift 3:

```html
        let fakeBgColorImageView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(color:UIColor.blue))
        addSubview(fakeBgColorImageView)
        // Autolayout with PureLayout, use whatever you want here
        fakeBgColorImageView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges()
        sendSubview(toBack: fakeBgColorImageView)
```

1. Add this code to the initialisers of a custom cell
2. Add the fake UIImageView with color as the background of the cell (NOT the content view!, because it will be resized and won't cover the reordering control, neither the (-) delete icon)
3. Send the view to the back, so it's behind the contentView

Comment: I don't see an initializer for `UIImage` that takes a color. Will you please tell me how that works for you?

Comment: @Amelia you can just use a convenience initialiser on an UIImage extension