# Change background color of UITableViewCell when reordering in editing mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I'm working on a application containing a UITableView. The only thing which needs to be possible for users, is to reorder the contents of the UITableView. When in editing mode the background color of the tableview cells turns transparent. Is there any way of keeping the original background color of the tableview cell when it's being reordered?

**Solution:**

After a few extra searches I found the (simple) solution.
By adding cell.backgroundView.backgroundcolor to the willDisplayCell method, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various scenarios when the iOS UI framework will make your cell transparent. One of them is the highlighted/selected state and another one is the reordering case.

The important thing is to understand how the system does it. The system hides the cell background (`cell.backgroundView` or `cell.selectedBackgroundView`) and for every view in the cell it sets `backgroundColor` to transparent color. Therefore, it's not possible to use `backgroundColor` to keep the cell opaque.

The simplest solution is to add a simple `UIView` with `drawRect:` that will fill the cell with a color.

```
@interface MyColoredView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIColor *color;

@end

@implementation MyColoredView

- (void)setColor:(UIColor *)color {
    _color = color;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self.color set];

    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), true);
    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.bounds);
}

@end
```

Add it to your cell (probably not to `contentView` but directly to the cell) and set its frame to match the bounds of the cell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried your solution, the tableviewcells are already initialized from a UIView. But nothing changed when I add these methods to the UIView. They are still transparent when I'm reordering them.

Comment: They can't be transparent if you do it correctly. Please, show your code.

Comment: I think it's because the color is declared in the viewcontroller and passed to the UIView of the cells. I'll try to post my code in a bit.

Comment: Great explanation of what is going on when reordering a cell! Another way to achieve the same result is to override `setBackgroundColor` and call `[super setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Say your cell color is redcolor

```
 [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

then set the tableview background to same.

```
 tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: To make my question a little bit more precise, every tableviewcell does have a separate color (like the clear app). So it would really be the Tableviewcell background color which I would like to change. Also because it turns transparent and when you move over another cell, you can see the cell underneath it trough the moving cell.