# Can a tableViewCell’s background color be animated while the cell is moved?

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, background-color

I animate the move of a `tableViewCell` using essentially the following code:

```
tableView.performBatchUpdates({ 
  tableView.moveRow(at: fromIndexPath, to: toIndexPath)
}, completion: nil)
```

My question is:

Is it possible to animate the cell’s `backgroundColor` property during the movement?

I tried to set a new `backgroundColor` in the `performBatchUpdates` block, but it does not animate.
I know I could use instead of `performBatchUpdates` instructions enclosed by `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`, but this is probably equivalent to using an `performBatchUpdates` block.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040730/change-background-color-of-uitableviewcell-when-reordering-in-editing-mode/21041704#21041704

Comment: @Nitish My tableView is **not** in editing mode. It is just re-ordered programmatically, and the cells keep their background color. I want to animate this background color during the movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@joncardasis/better-ios-animations-with-catransaction-72a7425673a6).  It can be done by using functions of core animation.
The `tableView.performBatchUpdates` block has to be enclosed in `CATransaction.begin()` and `CATransaction.commit()`, and a `CABasicAnimation` has to be set up for the `backgroundColor`:

```
    CATransaction.begin()
    tableView.performBatchUpdates({ 
        for (from, to) in movements {
            tableView.moveRow(at: from, to: to)
            guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: from) else { return }
            let backgroundColorAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.backgroundColor))
            backgroundColorAnimation.fromValue = cell.backgroundColor?.cgColor
            backgroundColorAnimation.toValue = kToBackgroundcolor.cgColor
            cell.layer.backgroundColor = kToBackgroundcolor.cgColor
            cell.layer.add(backgroundColorAnimation, forKey: #keyPath(CALayer.backgroundColor))
        }
    }, completion: { (finished) in
        // some code
    }
    )
    CATransaction.commit()
```

In this case, the background color of the moved cells is animated together with the movement. Of course, this is also possible for other animatable properties.