# UITableViewCell preserve background color and style when reordering (edit mode)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm facing a problem when reordering uitableview cells in my app. I want to preserve the background and the layout of original cells, but I'm having this.

This is a video of app: https://vid.me/j6wy

When reordering my cells have a clear background color and loose original layout, any suggestions?

EDIT: now I have this situation: https://vid.me/Df4p

Anyone knows how to preserve custom layout of cells?

Comment: I think these answers could help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132523/prevent-uitableviewcell-from-becoming-transparent-during-reordering

Comment: thanks for your comment, however i've not solved my problem, with that solution my cell are now like: https://vid.me/Df4p